# Use data asscociated with a DOM element just with PHP?

Tags: php, dom, post

You know [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) can be very useful, but can I use this in a form and to check it directly with PHP? Like `$_POST['inputValue']` but `$_POST['dataAttribute']` ? Or even to set it with PHP ?

Comment: You can set it when you generate your markup, but you can't read it from the client side without assistance from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I seem to see a lot of PHP developers forgetting is that PHP is a server language and can't really do much interaction with the client without the assistance of a client side language like Javascript.

You should be able to generate the data-* attributes on the server side with DOMDocument operations, or even by string concatenation if you're that old-fashioned.  If you use the DOMDocument approach modifying the values should also be pretty easy while you're in the process of building your DOM tree.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument ();
$elem = $doc -> createElement ('input');
$doc -> appendChild ($elem);
$elem -> setAttribute ('data-foo', '123');
// etc
```

As soon as you transform the DOM model to text for sending to the browser, any subsequent modifications become meaningless because they won't be reflected in the browser.

If you need changes made client-side to be known to the server, then you'll need to do some javascript in the client to collect all the data-values, serialise them and post them to the server.

Answer (score 1):

In order to past data values you can create hidden variables in the form with all data attributes you want before the **submit** event.

Html:

```
<div id="element" data-myattr="any_data_value"></div>
<form ...>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $("form:first").submit(function() {
          // any validation
          var v = $("#element").data("myattr");
          $("form:first").append('<input type="hidden" name="data_myattr" value="' + v  +'">');
         return true;
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Rendering data attributes using PHP:

```
<?php
     $myattrvalue= $_POST['data_myattr']; 
?>
<div id="element" data-myattr="<?php echo $myattrvalue; ?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmph. I've been working at this for 1+ hrs amid other things. Now there are other, very good answers.

Still, fwiw, here's another:

Here is an example where a div is hidden initially, and a data- attribute is used to decide whether the div should be revealed.

AJAX is used to communicate with a back-end PHP file that just spits out "yes" (if the field value is still "no", but otherwise spits nothing).

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var ax, dd, kk=0;

                dd = $('#hid').data('lnreq');
                if (dd=="no") $('#lnDIV').hide();

                $('#fname').keyup(function() {
                    if (kk < 4){
                        dd = $('#hid').data('lnreq');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:  "myprocessor.php",
                            data: "ddVar=" + dd,
                            success: function(recd) {
            //alert(recd);
                                $('#hid').data('lnreq', recd);
                                if ($('#hid').data('lnreq') == 'yes') {
                                    $('#lnDIV').show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        kk++; //Do only a few times
                    }
                });


            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
    First Name: <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" /><br />
    <div id="lnDIV">
        Last Name: <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" />
    </div>
    <input id="hid" type="hidden" data-lnreq="no" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP SIDE: **myprocessor.php**

```
<?php
    $rr = $_POST['ddVar'];
    if ($rr == "no") echo 'yes';
```